# Лампочка проверок загорается даже если очереди проверок не доступны

Tags: дефект, поддержка, предложение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если очереди проверок недоступны из-за лимита проверок в день или лимита голосования, они не показываются в списке проверок - тут все правильно.

Однако если в них есть новые сообщения - все равно загорается красная точка на иконке проверок. Это возможно исправить (ведь как-то сайт скрывает из списка проверки, которые недоступны)? Очень неудобно когда реагируешь на уведомления, а на самом деле ни одной новой проверки нет.

Comment: В теории, пока не исправят, можно свой userscript набросать, который будет проверять доступность проверок и зажигать/скрывать индикатор.

Comment: А можно просто использовать такой css: `.top-bar .secondary-nav .-link._danger-indicator:after {
    display: none;
}`